# Custom assignment operator for two classes that aren't my own

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I'm using two libraries, one is a linear algebra math library, and another is a physics library. Specifically I need to do converting between types vec3 and btVector3. I thought that I could simply do:

```
    void operator=(btVector3& lhs, const vec3& rhs)
    {
        lhs.setX(rhs.x); lhs.setY(rhs.y); lhs.setZ(rhs.z);
    }
    void operator=(vec3& lhs, const btVector3 rhs)
    {
        lhs.x = rhs.x(); lhs.y = rhs.y(); lhs.z = rhs.z();
    }
```

But I have found that global operator overloads are only allowed for certain compound operators such as +=, -= and so on. Apparently assignment operators must be single argument functions as non-static member functions. First of all I'm wondering why this is. I have seen other answers but I don't think I've seen the reason for this. Secondly, I have the additional problem that these two types, vec3 and btVector3 aren't my types, so I'd really prefer not to modify these classes (if I even can I'm not sure), can it be done simply in the headers of these classes?

Comment: I found a couple of assign functions, do you mean the std::function::assign() function? Ohhh, you mean create my own assign function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all I'm wondering why this is.

This is because of the rule of [three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). If you wish to define an assignment operator, you also need a copy constructor and a destructor. Since defining constructors or destructors outside a class is not allowed for obvious reasons, the assignment operator gets the same restriction.

> I have the additional problem that these two types, `vec3` and `btVector3` aren't my types, so I'd really prefer not to modify these classes

You don't need to do it. In a way, operators are "syntactic sugar" that lets you write less code, but in most cases you can do without them. Unless you need to use your operators in third-party contexts where an assignment operator is required, you can rewrite your operators as free-standing functions for the same effect - either like this (`std::swap` style)

```
void assign(btVector3& lhs, const vec3& rhs)
{
    lhs.setX(rhs.x); lhs.setY(rhs.y); lhs.setZ(rhs.z);
}
void assign(vec3& lhs, const btVector3& rhs)
{
    lhs.x = rhs.x(); lhs.y = rhs.y(); lhs.z = rhs.z();
}

// Use like this:
assign(myVec3, myBtVec);
assign(myBtVec, myVec3);
```

or like this (convert-and-assign style)

```
btVector3 convert(const vec3& rhs)
{
    btVector3 res;
    res.setX(rhs.x); res.setY(rhs.y); res.setZ(rhs.z);
}
vec3 convert(const btVector3& rhs)
{
    vec3 res;
    res.x = rhs.x(); res.y = rhs.y(); res.z = rhs.z();
}

// Use like this:
myVec3 = convert(myBtVec);
myBtVec = convert(myVec3);
```